# iOS remote build infinite attempt on Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Hi I'm trying use the remote build by following the instructions on 
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/#ios
But got stuck on infinite attempts, what did I do wrong?

[image: output from visual studio]
[image]

And when I try "remotebuild test" on a second window, I got this error message

[image]

Comment: Seems like the remote build is stuck updating the iOS platform for the project. Can you tell me where are you running the remotebuild from and does it have appropriate permissions to access internet (npm) to get the Cordova iOS platform?

Comment: Hi Subhag, thanks so much for helping, I'm running the remote build on my Macbook Pro, and it has no problem connecting to the internet. I've added more information about the error and hope it will help you to investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Node 4.0? If so then there is known issue of having race conditions causing deadlocks in the process which they have fixed in Cordova 5.3.3. So either use 5.3.3 of Cordova or a previous version of node (0.12.7) and I believe that your issue would be resolved.

Let me know what you find :)

Comment: Upgrade to 5.3.3 fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I use Cordova 5.4.1 and Node 0.12.9 but it still doesn't work, saying "Updating platform" forever, after upgrading to Xcode 8. Can you please suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when I install node @5.0.0 and cordova 5.3.3.
And I downgrade to 0.12.7, and doing fine.

[image: node version]